# RecyclerView в CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

Есть ли способ сворачивать при скролле `RecyclerView` другую вьюшку, которая выше `RecyclerView`? Как это сделать с `Toolbar` я знаю, но вот что-то не понятно как тоже самое провернуть с другими вьюшками?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот пример кода. Надо свой `View` поместить в `AppBarLayout`.
Здесь `layoutHeader` будет скролиттся при скролле `RecyclerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mkbPrimaryColor"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Обратите внимание на дополнительные атрибуты `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` и `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

`AppBarLayout` рекомендуется располагать ниже остальных элементов. При этом он все равно будет вверху страницы.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно использовать [Quick return pattern](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html)

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем. Мне нужно чтобы верхняя вьюшка не была частью `RecyclerView` т.к. хочу разнести их по разным `CardView`